# SignalR-Client-Cpp on Petalinux Throwing "Error in SSL handshake" Exception

Tags: c++, ssl, signalr, petalinux, signalr-client

I have a [Xilinx ZCU106](https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/zcu106.html) with a Petalinux build I created that includes an application using [SignalR-Client-Cpp](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp).  Despite trying a number of things, I'm continually getting an "Error in SSL handshake" exception after calling `start()` on my `signalr::hub_connection`.

This application runs fine on other Linux systems like Ubuntu.  I think the problem is it's having trouble finding the `ca-certificates.crt` file which is usually in `/usr/local/ssl` on more normal Linux distro's like Ubuntu.  In the Petalinux build it's located here: `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

The best I can tell, I need to do something like this to configure the `signalr::hub_connection` to use the certificate file:

```
web::http::client::http_client_config httpConfig;
httpConfig.set_ssl_context_callback([](boost::asio::ssl::context& ctx) {
    ctx.load_verify_file("/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"); });

web::websockets::client::websocket_client_config wsConfig;
wsConfig.set_ssl_context_callback([](boost::asio::ssl::context& ctx) {
    ctx.load_verify_file("/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"); });

signalr::signalr_client_config signalrConfig;
signalrConfig.set_http_client_config(httpConfig);
signalrConfig.set_websocket_client_config(wsConfig);

auto hubConn = signalr::hub_connection_builder::create(signalrURI).build();

hubConn.set_client_config(signalrConfig);

std::promise<void> task;
hubConn.start([&task](std::exception_ptr exception) { 
    // Code that checks the exception, etc
```

Yet, even when doing this, the exception that is passed into `start()` is populated, stating "Error in SSL handshake".

I've tried some other things like using `web::credentials` and setting those on the `signalr_client_config` before giving it to the `hub_connection` but I get the same results.

I'm out of ideas as to how to get this to work and I'm hoping someone else might have some ideas?

Comment: It's possible you're hitting an issue with those options not being properly copied into the internal http client. https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp/pull/78 may fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
web::http::client::http_client_config httpConfig;
httpConfig.set_validate_certificates(false);
signalr::signalr_client_config signalrConfig;
signalrConfig.set_http_client_config(httpConfig);

web::websockets::client::websocket_client_config wsConfig;
wsConfig.set_validate_certificates(false);
signalrConfig.set_websocket_client_config(wsConfig);
connection.set_client_config(signalrConfig);
```